# how to horizontal option value of listview item from view model in xamarin form

Tags: forms, xamarin

i have listview ,i need to set stacklayout horizontal option value based on condition from viewmodel.so how to set that

private string horizontalOption;

```
    public string HorizontalOption
    {
        get => horizontalOption;
        set
        {
            horizontalOption = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HorizontalOption));
        }
    }

public async Task FetchThreadUserData()
    {
     sing (HttpClient hc = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                IsBusy = true;
                var jsonString = await hc.GetStringAsync(url);
                var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessageList>(jsonString);
                foreach (var user in obj.messages)
                {
                    string authorIdStr = user.authorId;
                    if(authorIdStr==userId)
                    {
                        HorizontalOption = "StartAndExpand";
                    }
                    else if(authorIdStr!=userId)
                    { 
                    HorizontalOption = "EndAndExpand"; 
                    }
                    list.Add(user);
                }
            }
 and binding it like this in Xaml
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="{Binding HorizontalOption}" >
but it is not working .
```

Comment: Check the type of property before binding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CollectionView** in Forms if you want to let the list scroll in horizontal .**CollectionView** is released after XF 4.0 .

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding xxx}">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <ListItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

     <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

          //...
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

</CollectionView>
```

Don't forget to  adding the following line of code to your `AppDelegate` class on iOS, or to your `MainActivity` class on Android, before calling Forms.Init:

```
Forms.SetFlags("CollectionView_Experimental");
```

Comment: i want to set value of HorizontalOption programmatically according to condition which i have added above.

Comment: I don't suggest to use listview if you want to let it scroll  horizontal .

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use DataTriggers to change HorizontalOptions based on some ViewModel property value...

Update your Property like below...

```
public bool HorizontalOption
{
    get => horizontalOption;
    set
    {
        horizontalOption = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HorizontalOption));
    }
}
```

Now update your Xaml code like below...

```
<StackLayout>
//Your UI Elements here
  <StackLayout.Triggers>
     <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Binding="{Binding HorizontalOption}" 
        Value="True">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="StartAndExpand"/>
     </DataTrigger>
     <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Binding="{Binding HorizontalOption}" 
        Value="False">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="EndAndExpand"/>
     </DataTrigger>
  </StackLayout.Triggers>
</StackLayout>
```

Note:- Inside your method FetchThreadUserData() update HorizontalOption property value to True or False...

Hope this helps

Comment: Misleading property name.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you're binding a string to a property that accepts LayoutOptions.

```
public Xamarin.Forms.LayoutOptions HorizontalOption
{
    get => horizontalOption;
    set
    {
        horizontalOption = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HorizontalOption));
    }
}
```

Comment: set property like this andif (authorIdStr == userId)
                        {
                            HorizontalOption = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            HorizontalOption = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand;
                        }
                        list.Add(user);

Comment: but on ui side its not showing according to property value